# Why do I get "Not all arguments converted" when using %r with Tuples?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Please can someone explain why I get the following error when using %r with tuples?

```
>>> repr((1,2))
'(1, 2)'
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self,vals):
...             self.vals=vals
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return "Foo(%r)" % self.vals
... 
>>> foo = Foo((1,2))
>>> foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __repr__
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What is the appropriate way for printing out `__repr__`?  Should I be using `%s` and `repr(self.vals)` instead?

Comment: you can easily check for yourself about what happens when you use `%s`  how come you felt you needed to come here to ask it?

Comment: @InbarRose: because the behaviour is unexpected for someone not familiar with the `%` string formatting operator.

Comment: @Inbar "Please can someone explain why I get the following error when using %r with tuples?" is the reason why I asked this question.  I'm interested in understanding why I got the error and the most appropriate (Pythonic) way of dealing with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `%` operator takes a tuple itself, so you are basically doing this:

```
'Foo(%r)' % (1, 2)
```

Wrap `self.vals` in a one-element tuple:

```
'Foo(%r)' % (self.vals,)
```

In principle you can use a string defined in a variable too:

```
REPRFORMAT % (self.vals,)
```

in which case you want to leave it up to that variable (perhaps taken from a configuration file?) how to format `self.vals`, be it `%r` or `%s`.

You could also use the [`.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) instead:

```
return 'Foo({0!r})'.format(self.vals)
```

This format gives you more flexibility with the input given; you could address individual items in the `vals` tuple, for example:

```
return 'Foo(({0[0]:04d}, {0[1]:02d}))'.format(self.vals)
```

which would result in `Foo((0001, 04))` for your example input.

Comment: Is there a consensus on the "recommended" approach to use?  Personally I think "Foo(%s)" % repr(self.vals) is easiest to read, but as I mention above, it begs the question why you would ever use %r.

Comment: @Tim: The `.format()` string formatting method has been added to replace `%`, although the latter syntax is still hanging on in Python 3.

Comment: @Tim: Expanded a little, giving some arguments *for* using `%r`.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I hadn't come across `.format()` so far.  I think I'll stick with `%s` for now as I think it's more readable for my simple use case.